# add random forest predictions as column into test file

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, random-forest

I am working in python `pandas` (in a `Jupyter` notebook), where I created a Random Forest model for the Titanic data set. 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

I read in the test and train data, then I clean it and I add new columns (the same columns to both).

After fitting and re-fitting the model and trying boosts etc; I decide on one model:

```
 X2 = train_data[['Pclass','Sex','Age','richness']] 
 rfc_model_3 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
 %time cross_val_score(rfc_model_3, X2, Y_target).mean()
 rfc_model_3.fit(X2, Y_target)
```

Then I predict, if somebody survived or not

```
 X_test = test_data[['Pclass','Sex','Age','richness']]
 predictions = rfc_model_3.predict(X_test)
 preds = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['Survived'])
```

Is there a way for me to add the predictions as a `column` into the test file?

Comment: Isn't this just `X_test['Prediction'] = preds['Survivied']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

```
rfc_model_3 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
rfc_model_3.predict(X_test)
```

returns `y : array of shape = [n_samples]` ([see docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict)), you should be able to add the model output directly to `X_test` without creating an intermediate `DataFrame`:

```
X_test['survived'] = rfc_model_3.predict(X_test)
```

If you want the intermediate result anyway, @EdChum's suggestion in the comments would work fine.